# Error when joining tables with empty field values

Tags: mysql

I have a main table called `product_data` which i link to another table called `attrib_category`.

The `attrib_category` table has the fields `id`, `name`, `subcat`. Every record has an `id` and `name` however some records don't have values set for `subcat`, and I've noticed when I'm joining records from the `attrib_category` to the `prouct_data` that has no `subcat` value set it throws an error dealing with that record.

```
SELECT
  product_data.*,           
  attrib_categorymain.id AS attrib_categorymain_id,
  attrib_categorymain.name AS attrib_categorymain_name,
  attrib_categorymain.subcat AS subcat            
FROM product_data
LEFT JOIN attrib_categorymain ON attrib_categorymain.id = product_data.attrib_categorymain
```

Comment: What error it throws ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT product_data.*,
            attrib_categorymain.id                  AS attrib_categorymain_id,
            attrib_categorymain.name                AS attrib_categorymain_name,
            attrib_categorymain.subcat              AS subcat



    FROM product_data product_data
        LEFT JOIN attrib_category attrib_categorymain 
            ON attrib_categorymain.id = product_data.attrib_categorymain
```